# Text in my included tikz grahics should have the same font size as my main text

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, best-practices, standalone, workflow

I have a problem with the graphics and plots in my Latex document. I create all the plots and graphics with tikz in a seperate Latex standalone File, which produces pdf files.

Then I include these pdf files with \includegraphics into my main document.

This works so far. The problem I have is the following:

I need the texts inside my graphics and plots to have the same font size as the normal text in my main document. But when i include the pdf files and set its size in a way that it fits in the main document, the font size inside the grahics is of course changed too.

I would be very thankful if anyone has a workflow for graphics made with tikz that solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It seems to me that a natural way to solve the problem would be to set the fonts in the standalone documents in the same way as in the main document, and to build the figures to have the desired size directly in the standalone documents. Then you could include the figures in the main document without changing their sizes, hence without changing the font sizes. Is there a reason not to do that?

Comment: The simple solution would be to not compile the standalone files, but instead copy the code for the graphics directly in your main document (or save it in a separate file and load that file with `input{}`). Would that be acceptable, and if no, why not?

Comment: @Vincent The problem i have is that i don't know the dimensions of my main document while working in the standalone document. Is there a way to lay the main document dimensions "behind" the standalone page, so that i can estimate how big by graphic has to be? I need to do it because its guideline for my thesis

Comment: @Marijn Thanks for your Suggestion. But it's not really acceptable for me, because i excluded the generation of graphics on purpose so I save time on compiling the main document. I have very much graphics and plots. When I have to load them each time I compile my main document it would take too long.

Comment: @Vincent Additionaly the font size of included standalone graphics is variied in my main document without scaling the graphic. I just \includeprahics{xyz.pdf} and the resulting plot has smaller font than the text in my main document

Comment: @Jayzin if you are concerned about compilation time then you can use the `tikzexternalize` library (see chapter 52 on page 670 of the [TikZ manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf)) which does the same as your current approach (i.e., compile a figure once and use the compiled version for all future compilations until the code of the figure is changed) but then with the figures as part of the main document.

Comment: Hi @Jayzin!  Considering your problem, you should go with @Marijn 's solution.  Just to save some research  and test effort: 1) You must insert `\usetikzlibrary{external}` and `\tikzexternalize[prefix=extDirName/]` to have all the images in a directory created there where your document is.  2) After `\begin{document}` insert `\tikzexternaldisable`.  3) Before each`\begin{tikzpicture}`, insert  `\tikzexternalenable`.  After each `\end{tikzpicture}`, insert `\tikzexternaldisable`.